# How to pull information correctly from json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/KataCat-1203/blob",
dataType: 'json',
data: data, 
success: function (data) {
    $('#heroStats_elims').html(data.heroes.stats.competitive.roadhog.average_stats.eliminations_average);
}});
```

That is my .js file and this is where I'm trying to put the info in

```
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="page-header"><h2>Eliminations <small>Average</small></h2></div>
            <div id="heroStats_elims"></div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that the information isn't going into my div element, why is that? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pick one of the countries or `any` first from your response data.

It should be something like this:

```
$('#heroStats_elims').html(data.us.heroes.stats.competitive.roadhog.average_stats.eliminations_average);
```

Note that I added `us` after `data` and before `heroes`

Also, don't forget to check if values are null or undefined or empty before actually assigning the data to a variable or an element.  All of the other countries are null except `us` in your example.

Comment: Still no luck :/

    $.ajax({
    url: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/KataCat-1203/blob",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data, 
    success: function (data) {
        $('#heroStats_elims').html(data.us.heroes.stats.competitive.roadhog.average_stats.eliminations_average);
    }
});

Comment: Works for me, try this then look at your console:   $.ajax({
url: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/KataCat-1203/blob",
dataType: 'json',
data: "", 
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.us.heroes.stats.competitive.roadhog.average_stats.eliminations_average);
}});

Comment: Oh my lord, thanks for the help, the data: "", was part of the problem and it may have helped if I had remembered to import the jQuery js file... 

haha thanks for your help

Comment: @OskarSherrah, anytime

Comment: @OskarSherrah, make sure you mark this answer as "correct" ;)